# A way to adjust images size in a loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, image-size

is there a simple way to adjust images size in a loop in javascript? I tried something like this:

```
var img = new Image();

for (i=0; i<12; i++) {
  img = new Image();
  img.src = "./images/"+chosenImages[i];  // applies randomized images from a list
  img.onload = setSize;
  document.getElementById('img'+i).src=img.src;
}


  function setSize(){ 
    var height = img.height;
    var width = img.width;
    if (height > width) {
      var new_height = 150;
      new_width = 150 * width/height;
    } else {
      var new_width = 150;
      new_height = 150 * height/width;
    }
    document.getElementById('img'+i).height = new_height;
    document.getElementById('img'+i).width = new_width;
  }
```

But I got the error: *Cannot read property 'height' of undefined at Image.setSize*.

Any help?

Comment: Both, `i` and `img` in `setSize` are not what you think they are. You need a loop inside `setSize` too, to define correct `i`. Currently it is 12, because the `for .. i` loop has finished for a long time ago before the first `setSize` is executed. For the same reason you've to store the images in an array, otherwise you would handle the same image multiple times.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much.